How to call ravif crate from image crate input in rust
I am tring to add AVIF support using ravif crate because it's pure rust and no FFI needed.
However, I got error when using ravif crate to encode image from image crate. The encoder.encode_rgba() function returns 1x1 pixel image object, which mismatches the
original 150x150
Here is the code
use image::*;
use ravif::*;

// some unrelated codes

        // Init input and output files
        let img = image::open(&self.input_path)?;
        let f = File::create(&self.output_path)?;
        let mut buffered_f = BufWriter::new(f);

// some unrelated codes

                let (width, height) = img.dimensions();
                let encoder = Encoder::new()
                    .with_quality(75.)
                    .with_speed(1);
                let res = if img.color().has_alpha() { // RGBA image
                        let rgba = img.to_rgba8().pixels().map(|pixel| {
                                let [r, g, b, a] = pixel.0;
                                RGBA { r, g, b, a }
                            }).collect::<Vec<RGBA<u8>>>().first().unwrap().clone();
                        encoder.encode_rgba(Img::new(&[rgba], width as usize, height as usize))?
                    } else { // RGB image
                        let rgba = img.to_rgb8().pixels().map(|pixel| {
                                let [r, g, b] = pixel.0;
                                RGB { r, g, b}
                            }).collect::<Vec<RGB<u8>>>().first().unwrap().clone();
                        encoder.encode_rgb(Img::new(&[rgba], width as usize, height as usize))?
                    };
                buffered_f.write_all(res.avif_file.as_bytes())?;

// some unrelated codes

Here is the log of unit test
buffer len 1 is less than 22500 ((150+0)x150)
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
   2: imgref::iter::PixelsRefIter<T>::new
   3: imgref::Img<&[T]>::pixels
   4: ravif::av1encoder::Encoder::encode_rgba

According to the backtrace. I think it is some issue about data struct converion. The original code is using image crate to process image. I need to convert object from image style to ravif style correctly.
I am not an expert in Rust. I'm just tring to contribute to an opensource project.
I didn't get any helpful hint from IDE or official docs, nor Google, even nor Claude/GPT. That is why I ask here finally - Ask real human expert. I'd be really appreciate if somebody could shed some light for me.
